# Good Open Source Examples of NodeJS Applications?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

Are there any open source web applications written in Node?

I want to see how other people structure their node apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest ones I know are [Cloud9](https://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9) and [Calipso](https://github.com/cliftonc/calipso).

As of myself, I usually, break down code, if it is more than a certain amount that makes me very much frustrated(about 500 lines) and I put each file for one purpose. For example one class per file. As of making directories, beside the general architecture(MVC for example), I usually breakdown the files, and only putting the ones that need others in one directory. Trying to make everything isolated, and work by itself on testing.

Edit: [`npm`](https://github.com/npm/npm) and it's [website](https://github.com/npm/npm-www) are also good examples.

Comment: Sweet! here's the correct link for calipso: https://github.com/cliftonc/calipso

Comment: Corrected it. I saw a forum in node too, but I forgot the name.

Answer (score 0):

Have you see on GitHub. There are a few projects with code.
Es.
https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Projects,-Applications,-and-Companies-Using-Node

Comment: Yeah, but most of the projects there are not open  source, I'm searching for web applications code, not libraries.

Comment: This link is no longer valid.